# Based on $k$-fold validation scores, how do we decide if the model over-fits?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, overfitting

I am using 10 fold cross validation. I will get 10 accuracy scores of a model for 10 different training and test sets (correct if wrong).

After getting these scores, how do I decide if the model over-fits on the original, undivided data set?

Comment: The intuition should be, if you get way better fit on the full sample than on the folds, your model is overfitting. If so, you need to specify what is "way better" and what is not. If you were able to obtain the distribution of the accuracy scores from the 10 folds, you could assess at which quantile the full sample accuracy score lands, and see how extreme that quantile is. I will leave it at that, hopefully someone with more experience gives a more exact answer.

Comment: You don't? Randomly permute the target values instead & repeat the learning. For ten to one hundred times. (permutation test)

Comment: If you specifically want to diagnose overfitting, you should compute performance on both the training and test partitions during cross-validation. If the performance on the training partitions is far better than on the test partitions, you are overfitting.

Comment: The suggestion by @MarcClaesen is probably better if you have a lot of data.